# Trying to get a variable from other python functions to work with tkinter button commands

Tags: python, tkinter

trying to call variables from other functions but instead of grabbing only the functions it runs the function, which I dont want unless i push the button to let it which requires the variables.

Tried many things like creating global variables but it leads to them giving me errors as theyre not defined even when defining them.

````
import docx


#getfile method

def getfile():
    f1 = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[("Word Files", "*.docx")]) #<-- selects word files
    return f1

# admins screen after login


def home_page():
    global home_screen
    f1=getfile()#<-- these functions are used instead of grabbing the variable
    scan4yellow=scan_for_text()#<-- these functions are used instead of grabbing the variable
    home_screen = Toplevel(login_screen)
    home_screen.title("Home Page")
    home_screen.geometry("800x600")
    b1 = Button(home_screen, text="Select File", bg="white", command=getfile)
    l1 = Label(home_screen, bg="white", width="20")
    b2 = Button(home_screen, text="Scan File", width=8, bg="white", command=scan_for_text)
    b3 = Button(home_screen, text="Logout", width=8, bg="white", command=logout)
    b4 = Button(home_screen, text="Quit", width=8, bg="white", command=quit)
    l2 = Label(home_screen, text=f1, bg="white") #<-- should take the filepath selected in `f1` and show it
    l3 = Label(home_screen, text=scan4yellow, bg="white")
    return l2


def scan_for_text():
    #scan4yellow = scan_for_text()
    ##reads in the specific docx you want
    document = docx.Document(l2) #<--- reads in the filepath selected
    ##makes it so it is an element that is actually editable and usable
    rs = document._element.xpath("//w:r")
    ##microsoft words schema so it knows what the xml is like and the parametres
    WPML_URI = '{http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main}'
    ##bits and pieces to help find the highlighted pieces of text
    ##then leads onto if statements finding out the highlighted texts colour
    tag_rPr = WPML_URI + 'rPr'
    tag_highlight = WPML_URI + 'highlight'
    tag_val = WPML_URI + 'val'
    tag_t = WPML_URI + 't'
    for word in rs:
        for rPr in word.findall(tag_rPr):
            high = rPr.findall(tag_highlight)
            for hi in high:
                if hi.attrib[tag_val] == 'yellow':
                    scan4yellow = (word.find(tag_t).text.encode('utf-8').lower())
                    #return scan4yellow```
````

Answer (score 0):

Where you think your are "grabbing the variable", you are calling the function. One option is to create global variable 'f1' in '`getfile()` and `scan4yellow` in `scan_for_text()`. Something like this should work.

```
#getfile method

def getfile():
    global f1 # Make the global variable f1 here
    f1 = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[("Word Files", "*.docx")]) #<-- selects word files
    l2 = Label(home_screen, text=f1, bg="white").grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='W') #<-- should take the filepath selected in `f1` and show it

# admins screen after login


def home_page():
    global home_screen
    home_screen = Toplevel(login_screen)
    home_screen.title("Home Page")
    home_screen.geometry("800x600")
    b1 = Button(home_screen, text="Select File", bg="white", command=getfile)
    b1.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='W')
    l1 = Label(home_screen, bg="white", width="20")
    l1.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='W')
    b2 = Button(home_screen, text="Scan File", width=8, bg="white", command=scan_for_text)
    b2.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky='W')
    b3 = Button(home_screen, text="Logout", width=8, bg="white", command=logout)
    b3.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky='W')
    b4 = Button(home_screen, text="Quit", width=8, bg="white", command=quit)
    b4.grid(row=5, column=0, sticky='W')

def scan_for_text():
    ##reads in the specific docx you want
    document = docx.Document(f1) # Change this to f1
    ##makes it so it is an element that is actually editable and usable
    rs = document._element.xpath("//w:r")
    ##microsoft words schema so it knows what the xml is like and the parametres
    WPML_URI = '{http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main}'
    ##bits and pieces to help find the highlighted pieces of text
    ##then leads onto if statements finding out the highlighted texts colour
    tag_rPr = WPML_URI + 'rPr'
    tag_highlight = WPML_URI + 'highlight'
    tag_val = WPML_URI + 'val'
    tag_t = WPML_URI + 't'
    for word in rs:
        for rPr in word.findall(tag_rPr):
            high = rPr.findall(tag_highlight)
            for hi in high:
                if hi.attrib[tag_val] == 'yellow':
                    global scan4yellow # Make the global variable here
                    scan4yellow = (word.find(tag_t).text.encode('utf-8').lower())
                    l3 = Label(home_screen, text=scan4yellow, bg="white").grid(row=7, column=0, sticky='W')
```

Comment: Hi, i've added the global variables but it says that only f1 and l2 are not defined.
l2 isnt defined in `document = docx.Document(l2)` and f1 isnt defined in `l2 = Label(home_screen, text=f1, bg"white")`

Comment: I'd say that `document = docx.Document(l2)` should reference `f1` and not `l2`. I made an edit in the example above. Unfortunately I couldn't test it, since your code is incomplete.

Comment: edit: changed the labels for l2 and l3 to the functions `getfile()` and `scan_for_text()`